# 2 Rails Apps on Same Instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I'm trying to deploy host a production instance for my rails 4 applications. I can currently (and successfully) host them using `nginx`, `unicorn`, and `capistrano`.

To save money I would like to host both of my rails 4 apps on the same instance. Is it possible to host multiple production environments, which would ideally be connected to different domains?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run multiple rails applications by configuring each application to use a different unicorn socket.

You can then configure nginx sites (see /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.blah.com) to route to different unicorn sockets.

Have a look at these answers:
[multiple rails apps on nginx and unicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159689/multiple-rails-apps-on-nginx-and-unicorn)

Answer (score 0):

You need two separate virtual servers on nginx.

You can find more informations here: 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html