# Deploy different application on the same VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, vps

Is it possible to `deploy different applications` on the same `VPS` using `capistrano`, like on `Heroku` for example. Should I just change the folder that I am uploading to?

The resources that I found were referring more in deploying the same application in different states.

Thank you.

Comment: Sure you can, how you do it depends on what type of config you're using (nginx,unicorn etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a good answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12829840/256917, if you followed a tutorial to setup your first site then it's mostly doing the same thing but setting different locations